# ANTLR Grammar to distinguish words, alphanumeric and numbers

Tags: antlr4

I am still working my way through ANTLR and would appreciate any support for an enhanced version of this grammar.

**Here is an input string:**

> SYS [ErrorCode is not Available] : Transaction ID:
> d9d1211e-d273-40e1-bdd0-e4c9a8036ef3 . This can be ignored safely to:
> map To Not availble : works in progress

**Expected Parser Output:**

- words -> SYS
- specials -> [
- words -> ErrorCode
- words -> is
- ....
- alphanumeric -> d9d1211e-d273-40e1-bdd0-e4c9a8036ef3
- ...

**ANTLR Grammar I have so far came up with:**

```
grammar Expressions;

expression
            :
            | numbers? specials? words (numbers? specials? words)*
            | numbers words specials
            | specials words numbers
            | specials numbers words
            | words specials numbers
            | words numbers specials
            | specials specials? (specials specials? )*
            | words words? (words words?)*
            | numbers numbers? (numbers numbers?)*
            ;

words
            : CHARACTERS
            ;
numbers
            : NUMBERS
            ;

specials
            : AND
            | OR
            | EQUALS
            | ASSIGN
            | GT
            | LT
            | GTE
            | LTE
            | NOTEQUALS
            | NOT
            | PLUS
            | MINUS
            | IF
            | COLON
            | TLB
            | TRB
            | FLB
            | FRB
            | DOT
            ;

AND         : '&&'  ;
OR          : '||'  ;
EQUALS      : '=='  ;
ASSIGN      : '='   ;
GT          : '>'   ;
LT          : '<'   ;
GTE         : '>='  ;
LTE         : '<='  ;
NOTEQUALS   : '!='  ;
NOT         : '!'   ;
PLUS        : '+'   ;
MINUS       : '-'   ;
IF          : 'if'  ;
COLON       : ':'   ;
TLB         : '['   ;
TRB         : ']'   ;
FLB         : ')'   ;
FRB         : '('   ;
DOT         : '.'   ;


CHARACTERS
            : [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z]*
            ;

NUMBERS
             : [0-9]+
             | ([0-9]+)? '.' ([0-9])+
             ;

WS          : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip
            ;
```

Comment: It appears you’re trying to use ANTLR to “parse” a log entry.  Unless there’s a very defined grammer/syntax to those entries, you’d be much better served by a RegEx.  If you’re just trying to learn ANTLR, you’ll probably “get it” much more readily by working with a more structured input (even if it’s just building a simple little thing of your own design).   If you *really* want to pursue this line, you’ll get a better answer if you suggest something you’d like to be able to accomplish

Comment: Thanks Mike for pointing this out. I wrote a simple program to achieve the outcome I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrote this simple golang program to find if the string has any number in it.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {

    someString := "ID:8e038845-bd81-4218-9769-8406241fbb34 Operation is failed java.core.CoreRuntimeException: java.core.CoreRuntimeException: The JDBC connection information provided is incomplete"

    words := strings.Fields(someString)
    
    var tokens []string
    var x int
    for _, j := range words {

        if HasDigit(j) {
            dynamic := "$" + strconv.Itoa(x)
            tokens = append(tokens, dynamic)
            x++
        } else {
            tokens = append(tokens, j)
        }
    }

var tokenized string
tokenized = strings.Join(tokens, " ")

fmt.Println(tokenized)
}


func HasDigit(s string) bool {
    for _, r := range s {
        if '0' <= r && r <= '9' {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```